# Google Places API filter by "user_ratings_total" number or between range

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-api, postman, google-places-api

I'm trying to figure out a way to filter Places API results by number of user ratings despite the rating score, I've done something like this but it doesn't makes a difference : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=24.7588310%2C46.7330426&radius=10500&type=restaurant&user_ratings_total=15000&key=GOOGLE_API_KEY.

My actual goal is to have a result similar to (Example: Show list of restaurants with number or total ratings more than 1000 users and rating score with 4.5)

Your assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `user_ratings_total` is used liked that. It is only a value set for place details request and not a parameter itself. The parameter that usually uses it is the `fields` parameter for place detail request.

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#reviews_sort:%7E:text=Place%20Search%20requests%20and%20Place%20Details%20requests%20do%20not%20return%20the%20same%20fields.%20Place%20Search%20requests%20return%20a%20subset%20of%20the%20fields%20that%20are%20returned%20by%20Place%20Details%20requests.) says:

> *"Place Search requests and Place Details requests do not return the same fields. Place Search requests **return a subset of the fields that are returned by Place Details requests**."*

This means that the **reviews** and **ratings** that are being returned on your sample request are just a common result from nearby search. In this case **"a subset of the fields"**.

> *"To return one or more of these data fields for a place, make a Place Details request, pass a place ID, and specify which fields to return."*

ref: [Place Data Fields docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-data-fields#places-api-fields-support:%7E:text=To%20return%20one%20or%20more%20of%20these%20data%20fields%20for%20a%20place%2C%20make%20a%20Place%20Details%20request%2C%20pass%20a%20place%20ID%2C%20and%20specify%20which%20fields%20to%20return.)

A Place Details request looks like this: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/output?parameters`

And fields parameter can be added in this format: `fields=user_ratings_total`

In summary, `user_ratings_total` is not used to filter **Nearby Search** result, but it is used to get more **total ratings of a user in a certain Place/POI** using **Place Details** request.

I tried looking through the docs and I can't seem to find this feature on the Places API. So what you can do for now if your really want this feature, is to file a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=789309) on Google Issue Tracker and let it be reviewed by Google engineers if it is possible to be implemented on the API.

Answer (score 0):

have you found question about what you asked
Google Places API filter by "user_ratings_total" number or between range

I am not tech guy but for my personal use I like to know how to filter it,

If any how I can get results then I will thankful it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nope...........